# How to declare task dependency on tasks in 0.13?

Tags: scala, sbt

[In sbt 0.12, you could specify that one task depended upon another without actually using the output from the input tasks.](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html) So you were specifying purely an ordering on the tasks:

```
unitTask <<= Seq(stringTask, sampleTask).dependOn
```

There is no such example in the Tasks documentation for sbt 0.13. What's the new syntax for specifying said dependency?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the standard syntax, but ignore the results of the tasks used:

```
unitTask := {
  val x = stringTask.value
  val y = sampleTask.value
  ()
}
```

Because of a [bug in scalac](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7691), you have to use dummy names, otherwise you could just use `val _ = ...`.

Also, I prefer the more explicit way above, but it is equivalent to this shorter version because the results aren't used:

```
unitTask := {
  stringTask.value
  sampleTask.value
}
```

Comment: As per this definition, are these tasks (stringTask and sampleTask) guaranteed to be run in sequence, or is there no such guarantee?

Comment: @mark-harrah How to redefine an existing core task? E.g. I'd like to add a dependency on the compile task to create some application folders so these are available when the application is started. The folder creation in a new task is fairly simple, but trying to redefine the compile task causes a cyclic reference error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @HRJ Sbt will always try to do everything in parallel. There is a new feature in 0.13.8 which will allow you to define sequential tasks. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/sbt-0.13-Tech-Previews.html#Sequential+tasks

Answer (score 9):

The official [migration guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html#Migrating+when+using+%2C++or) recommends that instead of:

```
a <<= a dependsOn b
```

define it as:

```
a := (a dependsOn b).value
```

Answer (score 4):

Just like you did in 0.12

```
lazy val taskA= taskKey[Unit]("Prints 'Hello World'")
lazy val taskB= taskKey[Unit]("Prints 'Good by World'")
taskA := println("hello world!")
taskB := println("good by world!")
taskB <<= taskB.dependsOn(taskA)
```

As <<= is now deprecated see the answer above.

Comment: Interesting. So there's no equivalent using the := operator as there are for most other operations?

Comment: I could not find any other way (in the documentation and api).