# How do I add a task that when run runs compile first

Tags: sbt

I would like to run a task that depends on the compile task first (e.g. like run but runs with another main class)

The examples I see seem to use a value of the task that depends on. However I have no idea of what the compile's value is and I can't see why I care.

I assume that the required value is `(compile in Compile).value` what do I do with it.

For example have a hello task in build.sb

```
lazy val hello = taskKey[Unit]("Prints 'Hello World'")

hello := println("hello world!")
```

I think I have chnage the last line to

```
hello := {
  val dummy = (compile in Compile).value
  println("hello world!")
}
```

Is this correct?
If so what is the value of the compile and should I do anything with it

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely the best way to define the dependency.

See [How to declare task dependency on tasks in 0.13?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19297441/463761).

---

An alternative, perhaps just for academic reasons might be:

```
mainClass in Compile := Some("org.example.Main1")

val mainClass2 = taskKey[Option[String]]("Defines the alternative main class.")
val run2 = inputKey[Unit]("Runs the alternative main class, passing along arguments provided on the command line.")
run2 <<= Defaults.runTask(fullClasspath in Runtime, mainClass2 in Compile, runner in run)

mainClass2 in Compile := Some("org.example.Main2")
```

From `sbt shell`:

```
> run
[info] Running org.example.Main1
main1
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 20-Apr-2015 22:59:49
> run2
[info] Running org.example.Main2
main2
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 20-Apr-2015 22:59:48
```